# Why is PIL used so often with Pytorch?

Tags: python, opencv, pytorch, python-imaging-library

I noticed that a lot of dataloaders use PIL to load and transform images, e.g. the dataset builders in torchvision.datasets.folder.

My question is: why use PIL? You would need to do an np.asarray operation before turning it into a tensor. OpenCV seems to load it directly as a numpy array, and is faster too.

One reason I can think of is because PIL has a rich transforms library, but I feel like several of those transforms can be quickly implemented.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a discussion about adding OpenCV as one of possible backends [in torchvision PR](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/pull/34).

In summary, some reasons provided:

- OpenCV2 loads images in BGR format which would require wrapper class to handle changing to RGB internally or format of loaded images backend dependent
- This in turn would lead to code duplication in `functional` transforms in `torchvision` many of which use PIL operations (as transformations to support multiple backends would be pretty convoluted)
- OpenCV loads images as `np.array`, it's not really easier to do transformations on arrays
- Different representation might lead to hard to catch by users bugs
- PyTorch's modelzoo is dependent on RGB format as well and they would like to have it easily supported
- Doesn't play well with Python's multiprocessing (but it's no-issue as it was an issue for Python 2)

To be honest I don't see much movement towards this idea as there exists [albumentations](https://github.com/albumentations-team/albumentations) which uses OpenCV and can be integrated with PyTorch rather smoothly.

A little off-topic, but one can choose faster backend via [`torchvision.set_image_backend`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/index.html#torchvision.set_image_backend) to Intel's `accimage`. Also [Pillow-SIMD](https://github.com/uploadcare/pillow-simd) can be used as a drop-in replacement for PIL (it is supposedly faster and recommended by [fastai](https://docs.fast.ai/performance.html#pillow-simd) project).

When it comes to performance benchmarks they do not seem too reliable and it's not that easy to tell AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

There is some elements of answer [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/opencv-or-pil-image-which-one-is-better-for-pytorch/34001) and [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/i-wonder-why-pytorch-uses-pil-not-the-cv2/19482).

TL,DR: because of historical reasons, some benchmarks (never trust bencharcks, though) and because PIL is lighter and easier to instal than OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason PIL turns out to be frequent is because there are **lot of examples online** using PIL.Image.open method:

```
%matplotlib inline
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open(r"img.jpg")
# do more ...
```

Turns out that we don't need to use PIL, if we open the image using matplotlib.

```py
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
img = mpimg.imread(r"img.jpg")
_ = plt.imshow(img)
```

Jupyter notebooks frequent need is to show the image, and `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow` is used frequently for that.